# Paginate through json data with Flask

Tags: python, json, api, flask, jinja2

I am using flask and generate tables that are filled with the JSON data that I retrieve. The problem that I have now is that I need to paginate through all the JSON data, because the maximum per page is set at '50'and I want to show all the products in my table.

So far I can't get this working and I don't really know how to get it working with Flask. I tried using a while loop, but that doesn't work with Jinja2 because that command is not recognized.

This is my Python code:

```
@app.route('/products',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def products():
    shopnaam = request.form['shopname'] 
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    login = 'https://'+shopnaam+'example.com'
    url = 'https://'+shopnaam+'.example.com/admin/products.json'

    payload = {
          'login[email]': username,
          'login[password]': password
          }

    with requests.Session() as session:
          post = session.post(login, data=payload)

          r = session.get(url)
          parsed = json.loads(r.text)


    return render_template('producten.html',parsed = parsed)
```

This is my Jinja2 code:

```
<button class="collapsible">Bekijk product Informatie</button>
<div class="content">
<table id = "productentabel">
  <tr class = "header">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Titel </th>
    <th>Prijs Exclusief BTW</th>
    <th>Prijs Inclusief BTW</th>
    <th>Datum</th>

    {% for product in parsed['products'] %}
    <TR>
    <TD  width="100px" >{{product['id']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="300px" >{{product['nl']['title']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="150px">{{product['price_excl']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="150px">{{product['price_incl']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="300px">{{product['created_at']}}</TD>
    </TR>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

<input class = "exportknop" value="Exporteer product informatie" type="button" onclick="$('#productentabel').table2CSV({header:['ID','Titel','Prijs Exclusief BTW', 'Prijs Inclusief BTW', 'Datum']})">     
</div>
```

As you can see I am using a for loop, this code works, but the pagination is the issue.

My JSON looks like this:

```
products: [
{
article_code: "123",
barcode: "456",
brand_id: 2600822,
created_at: "2018-05-31T15:15:34+02:00",
data01: "",
data02: "",
data03: "",
delivery_date_id: null,
has_custom_fields: false,
has_discounts: false,
has_matrix: false,
hits: 0,
hs_code: null,
id: 72660113,
image_id: null,
is_visible: false,
price_excl: 33.0165,
price_incl: 39.95,
price_old_excl: 0,
price_old_incl: 0,
product_set_id: null,
product_type_id: null,
search_context: "123 456 789",
shop_id: 252449,
sku: "789",
supplier_id: 555236,
updated_at: "2018-05-31T15:15:34+02:00",
variants_count: 1,
visibility: "hidden",
weight: 0,

links: {
first: ".json",
last: ".json?page=70",
prev: null,
next: ".json?page=2",
count: 3497,
limit: 50,
pages: 70
}
```

So links is where the pagination happens, I tried the following in my Python code and with this I get all the values printed in my python terminal. Only I can't send the data to the tables.

```
while url:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            post = session.post(login, data=payload)
            r = session.get(url)
            parsed = json.loads(r.text)
            for product in parsed['products']:
                print(product['id'], product['nl']['title'])
            url = 'https://example/admin/products' + parsed['links']['next']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a couple things to consider here.  First, using a generator to create web content is going to be next to impossible outside of a websocket or async calls.  The reason is that WSGI needs all the data to come before it renders.  Then it closes the connection.  You can yield data, but in a table, this is going to cause problems in raw html.

What to do:

I would use something like datatables (datatables.net) feed your table data into a variable, and let datatables handle the pagination for you.

Example using Bootstrap 4 and DataTables.

```
<script>
var dataSet = []
var wurl = ""

tablex = $('#tablex').dataTable( {
    select: true,
    stateSave: true,
    colReorder: true,
    deferRender: true,
    "oLanguage": {"sSearch": "Filter:"},
    columns: [
        { title: "Number" },
        { title: "Client Name" },
        { title: "Opened" },
        { title: "Closed" },
        { title: "Worked" }
    ]
} );

function generate() {
$.get(wurl, function( data ) {
  dataSet = data;
  tablex.fnDestroy();
  tablex = $('#tablex').dataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    select: true,
    stateSave: true,
    colReorder: true,
    deferRender: true,
    "oLanguage": {"sSearch": "Filter:"},
    columns: [
        { title: "Number" },
        { title: "Client Name" },
        { title: "Opened"},
        { title: "Closed"},
        { title: "Worked"}
    ],
} );
});
};

$(document).ready(function() {
wurl = '/api/getdata';
generate()
} );

</script>
```

I first establish just a base table, and then I call an API and load that table with data in the background.  You could even have this poll and refresh the dataset on an interval if you wanted.  The API just delivers the raw data in a column output.

Your table id is "tablex" in this example.
Your API route can be anything, just a return value of your output that is in column and row format.

Comment: Hi @eatmeiamdanish thanks for your answer. So the only value that I have to sent from python to this script is the url? Or something else?

Comment: This is a generic example.  Obviously you would setup your columns with your own names.  But... All you have to do is have the api, in this case '/api/getdata' return a json list of lists, meaning you would return your rows inside of a list.  Datatables will do the rest for pagination.

Comment: Datatables also offers it's own server side pagination, but this gets complicated.  Each button press for the page sends an offset and a limit to the query, however this changes if you filter, so you have to account for that as well.  To keep things simple, if you have less than 100k rows, use client side with deferrender turned on.

Comment: I already had a feeling that this would get a little bit too complicated. So I went with an alternative solution with pushing the data first to the database and then retrieve it. Thanks for recommending Datatables, I am using it now :)

Comment: If you want any additional code that might help you, feel free to contact me privately.  I have a ton of time tested tools that can short circuit the complication.

Comment: @eatmeiamdanish Thanks, really appreciate it! Where can I contact you if needed?

Comment: my name plus gmail.